# Angular JS 2 not creating main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I followed the tutorial for Angular JS2 TypScript exactly adding the correct paths for my setup. And when I test it in the browser it says it can not find my main.js file. I tried testing after I start npm. When npm gets started it says "start: Unknown job: npm. Then I load up my browser run the main index file and it says  XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1/assets/scripts/app/main.js(…)

Here is my systemjs.config.js file

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: '',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:assets/angular/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'assets/scripts/app/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: 'assets/scriopts/app/index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Any ideas on what I have wrong? It seems like typscript isn't generating the main.js however i did install typscript and that worked fine as well as all the angular stuff without errors.

The app is being built to run inside of a existing web site as a nested application. Thus the reasoning for the odd file structuring of including the app files under scripts. The app gets called to a header_view of the site.

As requested here is the header file which contains the scripts for loading the libraries:

```
  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
         <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/angular/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/angular/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/angular/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/angular/systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script>
```

This app is being added to a Codeingiter application so what I just provider is the header_view

Then inside the main body I have the

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

so for file structure "hope this helps!"

index.php (created by views)

- assets folder

  - angular

    - node_modules (contains all core files for angular)
    - typings
    - package.json
    - systemjs.config.js
    - tsconfig.json
    - typings.json
  - scripts

    - app

      - app.component.ts
      - app.main.ts
      - app.module.ts

Also I was just following this tutorial below to get to this point.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#prereq

UPDATE 
here is my app.main.ts file

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from 'assets/scripts/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from ''app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you add your project's file structure? screenshot of it or a detailed list maybe

Comment: also add a html file where you have your scripts included (index.html or something)

Comment: tip: often angular is showing error that's something missed in files but the real problem is some bug in your code, are you using some typescript plugin in your editor to point your errors, or tsc compilation complain about something?

Comment: `unknown job: npm` is also suspicious, when you type `npm start` there is unknown job message?

Comment: yes it when i type npm start it says unknown job npm started

Comment: I added a example of the file structure as a list to the question

Comment: no bug in the app code yet since I haven't started making the app since I can not get the app to load the hello world message basically.

Comment: `npm start` is needed when you have no server installed but you working on php project so you don't need one

Comment: try to move files from angular directory to scripts dir and run command `tsc -p tsconfig.json` inside scripts dir

Comment: when I ran that command after moving it all. I get this message:
app/app.main.ts(2,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
app/app.main.ts(2,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
app/app.main.ts(2,41): error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.

Comment: ok so now we get something better than no main.js file :) now add your `app/app.main.ts` file here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is changed file structure(and some typos) which originally looks like

- app

  - app.component.ts
  - app.module.ts
  - main.ts
- node_modules ...
- typings ...
- index.html
- package.json
- styles.css
- systemjs.config.js
- tsconfig.json
- typings.json

you must move all angular project files to your `scripts` dir
then if your are using php (which you are) you don't need to run `lite server`
so run `npm run tsc:w` instead of `npm start` to watch files by typescript and compile it when something has changed

Comment: That command creates this result in the terminal
/media/sf_stage/assets/scripts$ npm run tsc:w

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w /media/sf_stage/assets/scripts
> tsc -w

app/app.main.ts(2,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
app/app.main.ts(2,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
app/app.main.ts(2,41): error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.
1:59:29 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.


the js files are now there though like app.main.js but the main page still says 404 for main.js

Comment: it is your main.ts file contains three lines of code (6 lines in general) ?

Comment: I just added the app.main.ts file to the post.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) you have quickstart repo of your app check if your files look's similar :)

Comment: you have typo at `import { AppModule } from ''app.module';` try `'./app.module'` instead

Comment: and replace whole path to file `'assets/scripts/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'` with just `'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'` systemjs will know where to find that file

Comment: ok so no more errors when I run that terminal command however I still get this error on the homepage: 127.0.0.1/:44 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1/assets/scripts/app/main.js(…)

I'm not sure why its looking for main.js and not app.main.js

Comment: because it should be `main.js` file not `app.main.js`, it should be `app/main.js` in `app` directory

Comment: The file that got created when I ran that command you provided is called "app.main.js"

Comment: remove `app.` prefix from `app.main.ts` file like `main.ts`

Comment: `app.` prefix is to tell that is an `application` `module` it is just good practice, but `main.ts` is main file that is only one per all project, there can be a lot of modules in your project but only one `main.ts` file like `login.component.ts` or `panel.component.ts` you name it

Comment: ok so it finally created it correctly but new errors show up on the dashboard for me instead of missing that file..

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/node_modules/assets/scripts/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: 127.0.0.1/:44 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1/node_modules/assets/scripts/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js(…)(anonymous function) @ 127.0.0.1/:44

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/node_modules/assets/scripts/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://127.0.0.1/node_modules/assets/scripts/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
system.src.js:373 Assertion failed: loading or loaded

Comment: so you must have wrong path to your files, probably in html file

Comment: I got it. paths were wrong in system config. It now works! Thank you so much for your help!